# I can't change a value in adjust last operation

Tags: modeling

I can change XYZ in the item panel like P1, but I can not change the value in "adjust last operation-move" after I move the cube like P2.

[image: item pannel]

[image: adjust last operation-move]

Comment: Maybe in Edit > Preferences > System > Memory & Limits, make sure that Global Undo is activated